# Struct use with printf()

Tags: c++

I am trying to expand an exercise in a book I am reading. The book moved from Struct > Pointers > `printf()`. The exercise asks to print out some information from the user using `printf()` instead of `std::cout`.

The error I keep getting is `Player::age` is uninitialized.

I am able to get the program to work without the `struct` so my question is why is `Player::name` fine but not `Player::age`??

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// example about structures
struct Player {
    string name;
    int age;
};

// main function
int main(){
    Player me;
    me.name; 
    me.age;

    string a = me.name;
    int b = me.age;

    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "\nEnter your age: ";
    cin >> b;

    printf("Name: %s, Age: %d", me.name.c_str(), me.age);


    cout << "\n\n\n";
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Here's a hint: where do you set the value of `me.name`?

Comment: `why is Player::name fine but not Player::age` Neither is literally "fine", but `name` is in a known state (empty string) while `age` has an unknown undefined value.

Comment: "The error I keep getting is Player::age is uninitialized." It's `me.age` which isn't initialized.

Comment: Thanks @dxiv! That answers a follow up question I had!

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to initialize the variables,
the other problem is you did not assign the input value to name and age.

```
me.name = a;
me.age = b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on several things.

1. Initialization
2. Constructors
3. Assignment

`Player me;`

This creates a default-constructed `Player`, `name` will be an empty string and `age` uninitialized.

```
me.name; 
me.age;
```

This does nothing. Were you expecting it to initialize these members? At a high enough warning level the compiler will warn about this

```
so4.cpp:14:8: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    me.name; 
    ~~ ^~~~
so4.cpp:15:8: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    me.age;
    ~~ ^~~
```

```
string a = me.name;
int b = me.age;
```

This assigns empty `name` to `a` and uninitialized `age` to `b`. It does not create `a` and `b` as aliases. Is that what you were expecting? If so, you should have used [`references`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

You probably meant

```
string& a = me.name;
int& b = me.age;
```

(Equally you could directly use your struct fields, i.e., `>> me.name`.

Last little niggle, no need for a semicolon after the closing brace for `main`. C and C++ are inconsistent in this case.